# How to count and display number of rows in database with the same date (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains three different columns: domain, date, length (in that order). What I'm trying to do is count the occurrence of every unique date in the database without knowing what the end date is in the database. The start date is always todays date.

So far I've only been able to count the occurences of a specific date, which requires me to put in an exact date.

What I want the PHP script to do is to start with todays date and output the number of times the date is mentioned (or the number of rows with that date) and then continue until it reaches a date that doesn't have a value (you could call this the end date).

I'm surprised and frustrated that I haven't been able to find the solution yet. It seems like a very easy thing to do.

I'd be super happy for any hints, tips or solutions.

Comment: can you show some sample data, and the desidered result?

Comment: an example of a row would be: domain.com|2013-10-12|6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of a `GROUP` and `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `occurrences`, `date` FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() GROUP BY `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `order by`

```
SELECT dateCol, Count(*) FROM myTable 
 WHERE dateCol >= date(now())
 GROUP BY dateCol
 ORDER BY dateCol ASC
```

Edit: SQLFiddle with your example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e86b/2

Comment: @user2008945 date(now()) will strip the time component from now. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/107

Comment: No,I did not mean stripping the date component, I meant about the comparison operator , its greater than now. Is it right?

Comment: @user2008945 Trying to address what I think you might be asking: 1. `>=` will work on dates. 2. date(now()) brings back the date info with the time zeroed out from the now() command, so will pick up anything that happened anytime today with the `>=`. Am I still missing your question though?

Comment: Sorry, nope, u did not get it yet :) i.e. I could not convey my question. Come to think of it I assumed the end date would be less than start date. That was where I was confused. If the end date is supposed to be greater than start date, then '>=' is fine.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Sorry, but I'm really new when it comes to databases. I've done some other php scripts where the results are echoed in a while loop, will I have to do something similar here?

Comment: What are your column and table named?

Comment: @sundquist updated with sqlfiddle if still having trouble. Some of the issue you might be having is the date column named date, generally you should not use date as a column name.